# Escape curly brace in sed when using find

Tags: sed, find

I have a problem with `find`:

```bash
find -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's|foo{}|bar{}|g' \{\} \;
```

Find will replace all occurances with the filename which is not correct. If I try to escape '{}' in the sed expression, like so

```bash
find -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's|foo\{\}|bar\{\}|g' \{\} \;
```

I get syntax error from `sed`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make `find` not replace `{}` in the argument to `-exec`.  Instead, modify the `{}` in the `sed` expression so that it's no longer exactly `{}`.  For example, you may just escape the `}`:

```bash
find . -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/foo{\}/bar{\}/g' {} +
```

This will avoid having `find` replace the `{}` in the arguments to `sed`.

The issue with escaping `{}` as `\{\}` is that it's an invalid regular expression.  Usually, one uses `\{` and `\}` in expressions like `A\{0,1\}`, which is the same as the *extended* regular expression `A{0,1}` or `A?`.  Using `\{\}` would have been fine if you had also used `sed` with `-E` to enable extended regular expression support.

Note that I changed the call to `sed` slightly in the `find` command so that `find` calls `sed` with as many found files as possible at once.

Comment: Which means that `find` does not have any escape mechanisms for the command, or?

Comment: @user877329 Yes, `find` will blindly replace each found `{}` with the current pathname. This depends on the implementation, but it's what GNU `find` and _most other_ `find` implementations do.

Comment: Hmm, it's somewhat interesting that `{\}` does work, since the similar `(\)` gives an error for unmatched parenthesis in all seds I tried. I'm sure there's some difference in how they're defined in the spec too, but I'm not going to look for it. Anyway, `foo[{]}` without even glancing at the special `\{` and `\}`. Or I guess one could switch to ERE, and _then_ use `foo\{\}`?

Comment: @ilkkachu You could use `foo[{]}` or `foo{[}]`, but you can't reuse that trick on the replacement side.  ... unless you capture the `{}`: `s/foo\([{]}\)/bar\1/g`, but then it's starting to become unreadable.  I think the main point is what the OP was getting at in their recent comment; There is no way to make `find` _not_ replace `{}` with the current pathname.

Comment: oh, right, the replacement part... Yes, not being able to control the replacement is  an issue with `find`. Too bad they indeed don't seem to have an option for controlling how the replacement works, to either change it to some other string, or to make it only work as a lone argument (which would be better wrt. unfriendly filenames anyway).